# UFT - Exporting datatable content to specific excel rows

Tags: excel, vbscript, hp-uft

I need some help on getting the data to be imported to the correct row in excel

I have a table in excel that has content in the first 5 columns on the first 3 rows, like this:
[image]

I need to get the data from the UFT datatable into the excel on the 2nd, 3rd rows but in the F, G column but when i run the script as is, the data is put into the 4th and 5th column(Like in the image), not the 2nd and 3rd like i need them to be

I have this function but am not sure how to fix it:

```
Public Function SetExcelCellData()
   Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
   Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\WrightJ\Desktop\Excel\CompFormTest.xlsx")
   Set objSheet  = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   Thank_you = Datatable("Thank you text",dtGlobalSheet)
   Prize = Datatable("Prize draw",dtGlobalSheet)
   rows = objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
   objSheet.Cells(rows+1,6).Value = Thank_you
   objSheet.Cells(rows+1,7).Value = Prize
   objWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\WrightJ\Desktop\Excel\CompFormTest.xlsx"
   objWorkbook.Close
   Set objSheet  = Nothing
   Set objWorkbook = Nothing
   Set objExcel = Nothing
End Function
```

Any help would be great!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UsedRange` returns a squared range of used cells, thus returning `A1:G3` in your case.

So when you call this line `rows = objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count`, the variable `rows` takes 3 as value.

To fix your code, delete the above line and replace following lines by:

```
objSheet.Cells(2,6).Value = Thank_you
objSheet.Cells(2,7).Value = Prize
```

Comment: Although be aware that your code isn't flexible, and you will need to adapt it if you sheet organisation changes.

Comment: thanks for the help. Let's say I'm running 2 iterations during the one script so I want the 2nd iteration to be on the row below instead of overwriting the first iterations  Data in Excel on the 1st row. So it stores the data of the first iteration on top row and right below it stores the 2nd iteration just incase the data is different between each. How would I do that?

Comment: Do you know if data ```Thank_you``` and ```Prize``` will always be in row 6 and 7 respectively ?

Comment: Yes it's always going to be in those rows.

Comment: You can use ```iLastRowF = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row``` and ```iLastRowG = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row``` to find the last used in F and G columns (in case they are 2 seperate values).  Then use ```iLastRowF```` and ```iLastRowG``` when you give coordinates for destination cell, which gives ```objSheet.Cells(iLastRowF,6).Value = Thank_you```. This way, you are sure your new data are put below used cells of the column, no matter when you execute your script.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more thing, When i run the script with this, I get an error saying "Object required: 'sht' Line (8): "iLastRowF = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "F").End(x1Up).Row". Do i need to set an object somewhere above this line?

Comment: 2 choices: either you don't use ```sht``` and ```ActiveWorksheet``` will be taken to calculate ```iLastRowF```, or you use ```sht``` which means you need to declare it at the beginning of your script and give it a value according to your sheet name or index ```sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(YourSheetNameOrIndex)```